# In R is there a way I could cut all rows out of a table that have one value in one of the columns?

Tags: r

I am attempting to remove all the rows from a table that include a certain value. I have attempted to use the exclude function but it did not work as it comes up with "object not found".

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: What do you mean by value--a string, a numerical value?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following dataframe:

```
df <-merge(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k"),
      c(1:10))
```

And you want do get rid of all the "a"-values:

```
subset(df,!x %in% c("a"))
```

If you want to filter for all "a"-values:

```
subset(df,x %in% c("a"))
```

Note the ! before the x that makes the difference.

Edit: If your "value" is numeric and you want to get rid of all values in y greater than 3, for example:

```
subset(df,y >3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c("Ann", NA, "Bert", "Jim"),
  b = c(1:4),
  c = c("I", "love", "you", "Ann")
)
```

You can `filter` out (i.e., remove) all rows where, for example, the string value "Ann" occurs `in_any` column like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  filter(!if_any(everything(), ~str_detect(., "Ann")))
     a b   c
1 Bert 3 you
```